# Outlook becomes white when run Process.Start("Outlook.exe", "/recycle")

Tags: outlook

I'm developing a VSTO add-in, I need to re-active(open) Outlook when its "MinToTray" is enabled(by the context menu in the tray of Outlook icon).
I use **Process.Start("Outlook.exe", "/recycle")** to do this. And it works. Except, for the first time when Outlook is re-open, its Title bar, Ribbon area, and Command bar become white, unless I resize the Outlook window.

Image [https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuKOZ.png]

Does anyone know how to fix this? It is very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `Application.ActiveExplorer.Activate` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dmitry Streblechenko. Application.ActiveExplorer.Activate will not work when Outlook is minimized and hidden (Check on the context menu of the Outlook icon in system tray);

I fixed it by myself. Needs to expand my VSTO panel until Outlook is completely recovered from minimized and hidden state.